# VS Code & Incremental Typescript Compiling

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I cannot find a clear information on the topic if I can get Typescript to just recompile the changed .ts files in Visual Studio Code. 
I can run "tsc -w" (or via task) and "webpack --watch" and get everthing done, but tsc always rebuilds every file, thus triggering webpack to rebuild my whole project.
As it is a growing angular2 project this consumes a lot of time.

In Visual Studio 2015 typescript somehow manages (via compileOnSave: true option?) to only compile my changed file.

Can I get that behavior in Visual Studio Code aswell?

Thank you :)

UPDATE:

Apparently webpack alone should work, but somehow my config does not pick up changes on .ts files. Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
    /// <binding />
"use strict";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "polyfills" :  path.resolve("./wwwroot/app/base/polyfills"),
        "app": path.resolve("./wwwroot/app/base/main"),
        "vendor": path.resolve("./wwwroot/app/base/vendors")      
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',    
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js",
        path: "./wwwroot/dist/",
        publicPath: "./dist/"
    },
    watch: true,   
    resolve: {       
        extensions: ['','.js','.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            //Typescript
           { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
            // SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style','css','sass'],
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
      {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader: 'html'
      },
            // Fonts & Files
            {
                test:  /\.(ttf|eot|txt|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader' ,
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
    //new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin(),
        //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        //    compressor: {
        //        warnings: false
        //    }
        //}),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
         new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
             name: ["app","vendor","polyfills"]
         }),

          new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
              template:  './wwwroot/index.html'
          })
    ]
};
```

Node version: 4.5.0 / webpack 1.13.2 / ts-loader: 0.8.2 / Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

> and "webpack --watch" and get everthing done, but tsc always rebuilds every file, thus triggering webpack to rebuild my whole project

You should not use `tsc -w` with webpack. Just use `ts-loader` and webpack will incrementally compile just fine.

## More

Quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.. unfortunally something seems wrong with my webpack config, as it does not recognize file changes ... updated my question with my config.

Comment: Nothing.. I change a ts file, and webpack/ts-loader does... nothing :(

Comment: Got a little further : First Error were my entry points: I forgot the .ts -extension, so webpack took the .js files as entrypoint and was only watching them.  But now I have the problem, that webpack only triggers on changes to entry-point files...

Comment: Not really...   currently I am running "tsc -w" and webpack in watch mode. With Typescript 2.0.2 it just rebuilds the changed files. In my medium-sized project it takes ~3-5 secs, which is not perfect but acceptable. I decided to not spend more time on that till I switch to webpack 2